# React-native run-android take too much time

Tags: android, windows, react-native

I'm on Windows and i'm working with react-native since 2 weeks. But now, it takes too much time to run my application on my devices.

```
Scanning 835 folders for symlinks in D:\workspace\react-
native\MonCompte\node_modules (31ms)
Starting JS server...
Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat 
installDebug)...
> Configuring > 3/5 projects > Resolving dependencies ':app:_debugApk' > 
Resolving dependencies ':react-native-vector-icons:_releaseCompile'
```

It seems to "freeze" at this point. After more than 25 minutes it finally builds !

Is someone have an idea please? Thanks !

Comment: what's your PC configuration?

Comment: i5-6500 3.20Ghz / 8Go RAM / Windows 10. But yesterday it took less than 1min to run it

Comment: try cleaning watchman cache. `watchman watch-del-all`

Comment: No watchman for windows. (There is an alpha i tried this but it doesn't work)

Comment: Any ideas? I still don't find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I finally found a solution.

It was because my proxy wasn't in the gradle.properties file !

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=http://myproxy.proxy
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyHost=http://myproxy.proxy
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
```

Comment: Can this same solution be applied on linux

Comment: how and where to apply this ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure these lines are not included in `android/build.gradle`:

```
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools' }
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/firebase/gradle/' }
```

If it does include them, then delete or simply comment these lines out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out i was not connected to the emulator, so I closed the emulator and android studio app, and ran it. react-native run-android restarted it and it installed as quickly as it used to.